# How to find DRM protected WMA files on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: windows, media, drm

On my **Ubuntu Linux 18.04** machine I have a whole bunch of WMA files (don't ask) which have gotten mixed up with several files from another computer that are DRM protected. The latter won't play and even crash some player software.

Is there a quick-and-easy way to recurse through the entire subdirectory tree and detect which WMA files are DRM protected? I've seen solutions based on Windows XP and Powershell, but nothing for *ix.

Mind you, I'm NOT looking for a (legally dubious) way to strip off the DRM protection; I just need to find out which ones are DRM protected without trying them out one by one so I can remove them.

Advise to discontinue the use of WMA and switch to more sensible formats instead is unnecessary; I never use WMA if I can possibly avoid it. However, the people who pay for my meal ticket require me to support this [censored] so I have little choice.

Comment: heh, do you have the player software that crashes on DRM'ed files? a) fix that bug if you can b) use that crash as method of detecting DRM

Comment: what *are* the solutions for powershell? Maybe the same methodology applies for detecting whether a file is DRM-protected.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034360/how-to-detect-the-usage-rights-drm-of-a-file
But as I  said that's only for Windows, not *ix
Also, using a player crash will work but that requires testing each file manually. I need to get this done while I'm still middle-aged. :-)

Comment: The trick would be to automate the crashing. Which player is this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a quick-and-easy way to recurse through the entire subdirectory tree and detect which WMA files are DRM protected?

sure! What you'll need is to provide a program of any kind to detect whether a file is DRM-protected. The recursing part is easy. You're probably using `bash`, so this script recurses, checks, prints DRM'ed files ; it could delete them as well, if you replace the `echo` with an `rm`.

```bsh
# to make bash understand **; ZSH doesn't need this
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nocaseglob
for candidate in **/**.wma ; do 
  magic_command_that_fails_with_drm "${candidate}" || echo "${candidate}"
done
```

If you happen to have a command line program that reliably crashes with these files, well, that could work as `magic_command_that_fails_with_drm`. Otherwise, try `mplayer -really-quiet -vo null -ao pcm:fast:file=...`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# to make bash understand **; ZSH doesn't need this
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nocaseglob

for candidate in **/**.wma ; do 
  tmpfile=$(mktemp)
  mplayer -really-quiet -vo null -ao "pcm:fast:file=${tmpfile}" "${candidate}" 2> /dev/null
  # check whether file exists and is non-empty
  if [ ! -s "${tmpfile}" ]; then
    echo "${candidate}"
  fi
  # delete the PCM file again.
  rm "${tmpfile}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ffprobe` (comes with `ffmpeg`) and `grep` for the string "DRM":

```bash
find . -iname "*.wma" \
| while read -r f; do
    ffprobe "$f" 2>&1 | grep -q ' DRM' && echo "$f";
  done
```

Or the same as a one-liner:

```bash
find . -iname "*.wma" | while read -r f; do ffprobe "$f" 2>&1 | grep -q ' DRM' && echo "$f"; done
```